# how to send extra parameters to the client when he requests list of data

Tags: rest, architecture, http-headers

I'm implementing pagination in my rest-architected application. Client sends `GET` request with extra params (offset, limit) and server returns `array` of data items. Client also needs extra parameter - `count` (number of all items we have in the db, this is required for pagination). The question is HOW to send this parameter to the client? I see two options:

1. send response like:

   `{
     count: 2,
     items: [ ... ]
   }`
2. send parameter in the response headers, like

   `Items-count: 2`

The problem with first option is that client expects array of items, not object that contain items.
The problem with second option is that I dont know if its a good desgin. Is it? Is there another options?

Comment: You don't need to limit yourself with "GET replies with list". Client should expect a **model** in response, and model can contain any kind onf additional information - paging, next-prev links, performance counters, diagnostics info.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 main approaches by REST pagination.

- You can use [range headers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html).
- You can use links with next, prev etc... [link relations](http://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml) by a hypermedia response like [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html). (Alternative: use RDF with [a vocab having pagination](http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/spec/latest/core/) description.)

I guess what you are talking about is a CRUD application with plain JSON responses. Now [that is not REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS)...

Comment: What is the best practice? And what do you mean by *"Now that is not REST..."*

Comment: There are REST constraints. Not using links violates the HATEOAS constraint. There is no best practice, REST is too new for that. I would use HAL with link relations if I were you. It is easier to learn than RDF, and I think a better approach than range headers.